# Setting items for IDs

Tags: python, linux, windows, macos, io

Curious as to how I'd be able to create a list of numbers/names to a file to reach them later. Like a list of IDs that are for a specific item each. All for python EX:

```
IDs = ('open', 'IDFile.txt', 'a') #For storing info
info = input(str("Enter ID: ") #ID for storing, can be number or letter
```

I'm just not sure how I would get it to store the info and have it be accessed later with another command. I'm going to attempt to using this code for a sorting system which will involve more but I want to get this part done.

Comment: Have a look at [Shelving](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a dictionary to store string and integer based id's.  I would then use JSON to write the data to and from a file.

### Storing Id's

```
import json
ids = {
        "id1":45,
        "id2":"john"
    }
with open("IDFile.json","w") as fo:
    json.dump(ids,fo)
```

## Retrieving Id's

```
import json
fetchedIds={}
with open("IDFile.json","r") as fi:
    fetchedIds = json.loads(fi.read())
print(fetchedIds)
```